# Update subarray of objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document in my database:

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId(...)",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "_id": "ObjectId(...)",
            "link": "128371.html",
            "content": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The chapters array can have up to 3k items, and I have to populate each content attribute with some info. I want to be able to save the info I want inside the right object. Until now I was able to change the content attribute generally (in all items), but I am having trouble filtering it. This is what I managed to code using what I found in other questions:

```
let content = "Testing";
await models.ListNovel.updateOne(
  { link: novel_link },
  { $set: { "chapters.$[].content": content } }
);
```

I saw that `{ arrayFilters: [{ link: { $eq: chapter_link } }], multi: false }` may work in some cases, but I don't use the link identifier in the update.

Thank you!

### UPDATE

Similar to Suleyman's solution, I ended up with the following working code, I hope it may be useful for you.

```
await models.ListNovel.updateOne(
  { link: novel.link },
  { $set: { "chapters.$[elem].content": content } },
  {
    multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [{ "elem.link": { $eq: chapter.link } }]
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in `updateOne` must match parent object, but you are using `{ link: novel_link }` which belongs to the inner array object field, so it cannot find the document, and update doesn't happen.

To illustrate this, let's say your schema is like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  chapters: [
    new mongoose.Schema({
      link: String,
      content: String
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ListNovel", schema);
```

Let's have this existing document in this collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e39",
    "name": "Novel1",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e3b",
            "link": "128371.html",
            "content": ""
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e3a",
            "link": "222222.html",
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

If we want to update this document's chapter with `"link": "128371.html"`, first we need to find it with name or _id field, and update it using the [filtered positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

```js
router.put("/novels/:name", async (req, res) => {
  const novel_link = "128371.html";
  const content = "Testing";

  const result = await ListNovel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { name: req.params.name },
    {
      $set: { "chapters.$[chapter].content": content }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ "chapter.link": novel_link }],
      new: true
    }
  );
  res.send(result);
});
```

Here I used `findOneAndUpdate` to immediately retrieve the updated document, but you can also use the `updateOne` instead of `findOneAndUpdate`.

The result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e39",
    "name": "Novel1",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e3b",
            "link": "128371.html",
            "content": "Testing"  // => UPDATED
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e498a1fe21eea0e10690e3a",
            "link": "222222.html",
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, Suleyman! After some time going through the documentation, I ended up with a pretty similar solution, using updateOne and the $eq operator.